# Excel help, Sum Row with criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

Example:

[image: Example]]

How can I sum total G3:X3 in Y3 , but only sum if "paid" criteria is met. sum (feb,Q1,Apr,1H)

Comment: Have you had a look at =sumif()? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: yes i have, ive tried looking for tutorials at youtube but all the tutorials were by column not rows.

Answer (score 4):

Use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(G3:W3,"Paid",H3:X3)
```

Note the same size but offset ranges.

Comment: oh wow this works, thankyou for this you made my job easier

Answer (score 1):

This formula will sum numbers in the given range that has "Paid" in the cell LEFT of them:

`=SUM(IF(OFFSET(H3:M3;0;-1)="Paid";H3:M3;0))`

... now, this is a "3D-formula" so edit/type in and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> at the end
*(NOTE: <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in LibreOffice)*

If you press JUST <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the sum will be "0" regardless of "Paid" being present.

I typed in H3:M3 instead of H3:X3 as you have columns with Q1, Q2 and H1 as headers; assuming you do NOT wish to have these make the sum be double the actual total.

Comment: Note:  In excel, Offset is a volatile function.  This is not the end of the world, it just means that the functions will recalculate anytime information changes on a worksheet/workbook even when it does not affect the formula.  Regular formulas only recalculate when something that affects them changes.  In small batches not so bad. When repeated over a large number of cells, it could get cumbersome to work with the sheet.

Comment: thankyou for your alternatives, ill use this if i have the chance . thanks

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this solution:

[image]

Where the Formula inside the Cell next to "Total" is in this case

```
=SUMIF(D2:D11;"Paid";E2:E11)
```

that way you can filter out "paid" or "bill" or sort by amount with ease

Comment: thankyou for your suggestions, i  also prefer that solutions. but it needed to be in only 1 rows. thanks again though

Answer (score 0):

In a similar concept to Scott Craner's answer, you can offset the ranges.  This will have the effect of lining G3 with H3 and so one down the row.  Scott's answer used `SUMIF` function.  This solution will use the alternative of `SUMPRODUCT`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($G3:$W3="Paid"),$H3:$X3)
```

Note SUMPRODUCT performs array like calculations.  Make sure your limit it to your data and do not use full column/row references.

The better formula in my opinion is SUMIF.  This was simply a demonstration of an alternative.

Comment: thankyou for your answer ill use it when i can, thanks